# Using Javascript or HTML, how to get the height and width of a div or other element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying for a while now to 'get' the height and width of a div on my webpage. I've tried many things, some are:

```
document.getElementById("header").getHeight();
                                 .height();
                                 .height;
                                 .pixelHeight()
```

and all other 'obvious' possibilites. Any help please? Its just a simple div with a width and a height:

```
<style>
    #header {
        width: 500px; 
        height:100px; 
        background-color:black; 
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="header" style="position:absolute" onclick="testjs()" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var hdiv = document.getElementById("header");

        function testjs()
        {
            hdiv.style.height="221px";
        }           

        /////////////////////////////////////
        hdiv.getHeight();              ???????
        //////////////////////////////////////
    </script>
```

I want to 'get' the div's height and width because eventually the user will be able to alter the height and width dynamically.

Comment: are you using jquery or native javascript?

Comment: `offsetHeight`, `offsetWidth` might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to get height use

```
document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight
```

and for width use

```
document.getElementById("header").offsetWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) offsetHeight works perfectly. Thanks for everyone elses answers too. I"m going to look into jQuery right now. Seems like its really useful. Accepting answer in 5 minutes

Comment: yup, jQuery is very easy as compare to native javascript. it will be good to move on to jQuery

Answer (score 3):

You should think about getting jQuery, as then you can just this and more very easily:

```
$("#header").width(); // Gets the width;
$("#header").width(50); // Set width to 50;
$("#header").height(); // Gets the height;
$("#header").height(50); // Set height to 50;
```

It'll make your life a lot easier in the long run too. Writing with native Javascript can be cumbersome as it requires more code and lots of cross browser testing.

Comment: Please don't suggest the use of an external library to do things that are trivially done without it. There is no [tag:jquery] tag on this question.

Answer (score 0):

example -

```
var divheight = document.getElementById('divId').offsetHeight;
```

refer this -

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use jQuery try this:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').clientHeight;
document.getElementById('someDiv').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('someDiv').scrollHeight;
```

Depend what you need.