# how to get the height/width (or other properties) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After changing the height/width(or other css properties) of a div element using jquery-ui resizable how can i get the new properties and save it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436875/using-javascript-or-html-how-to-get-the-height-and-width-of-a-div-or-other-elem?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can add handler for `stop` event. According to **[jQuery UI API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop)**:

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.size;  //The current size represented as { width, height }
      ui.originalSize; //The size represented as { width, height } before the resizable is resized
  }
});
```